# Import shows changes on product, but not front of site

Tags: import, sale-price

Trying to upload an **excel sheet** to **update products** for upcoming sales, and the changes are being placed on the product, but not on the front end.

I have one product that I set to have a 15% discount. Uploading the CSV shows that the 15% is in the back end of the product, but on the front of site it does not list it as for sale.

Sale coming up is going to have over 500 products and I do not want to go in to each one and hit save just so the sale is enabled on the product.

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Its may be reindex issue. Please reindex and clear the cache.

Comment: No its not a re index and cache issue. That has been done every time. Probably a custom attribute issue and need to buy some $300 plugin just for 1 thing to work.

Comment: Do you have flat tables enabled on your website?. Do you have any custom cache plugin installed? Which Magento version?